# Difference in difference with interaction (Part 2)

Tags: interaction, difference-in-difference

I'm conducting a difference-in-difference analysis, where I believe that my treatment effect is driven by a specific set of treatments (e.g., treated by a higher qualified teacher, compared to treated by a low qualified teacher (both groups are mutually exclusive)).
To test this, I implemented the analysis by splitting my original treatment group in two parts and including both dummies into the equation:
$$
Y=\alpha+b_1*Post + b_2*TreatLow+b_3*TreatHigh+b_4*Post*TreatLow+b_5*Post*TreatHigh   
$$
I get reasonable results, meaning that the coefficients and standard error look sensible. However, after reading more on the matter (incl. this post [Difference in difference with interaction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183302/difference-in-difference-with-interaction)), I'm wondering whether this is the correct approach or I should rather use Triple-DiD instead.

Edit: I have an unabalanced panel dataset, where I can observe students over time. Students are nested within teachers and teachers can be either high or low qualified. The treatment is at the teachers' level.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Do you have a panel dataset? Do you observed students across time? Are the students nested within schools? Describe how your data is organized and we can help you further.

Comment: @ThomasBilach Thanks for the feedback! I edited the question.

Comment: So you are observing students $i$ across time periods $t$? And since treatment is at the *teacher level*, it should affect all students within the classroom. Correct?

Comment: Also, do you observe students across multiple schools?